# Split File into a Multidimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm loading flies in this format:

```
///mvid:417815 qty:2 name:Aether Hub loc:Deck
2 Aether Hub
///mvid:423770 qty:2 name:Aetherstream Leopard loc:Deck
2 Aetherstream Leopard
///mvid:401837 qty:4 name:Canopy Vista loc:Deck
4 Canopy Vista
///mvid:426709 qty:2 name:Cartouche of Solidarity loc:Deck
2 Cartouche of Solidarity
```

What I'd like to do is load into an array where I have the following structure (I need to ignore every other line as well):

```
417815|2|Aether Hub|Deck
423770|2|Aetherstream Leopard|Deck
401837|4|Canopy Vista|Deck
426709|2|Cartouche of Solidarity|Deck
```

Comment: where is code ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: What have you tried already? Do show some effort rather than just dumping complete problems/assignments here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you are getting that format for loading but if you have it in a variable here's the code you can use to achieve want you said.

```
<?php
    $values = [];
    $content = "///mvid:417815 qty:2 name:Aether Hub loc:Deck
2 Aether Hub
///mvid:423770 qty:2 name:Aetherstream Leopard loc:Deck
2 Aetherstream Leopard
///mvid:401837 qty:4 name:Canopy Vista loc:Deck
4 Canopy Vista
///mvid:426709 qty:2 name:Cartouche of Solidarity loc:Deck
2 Cartouche of Solidarity";

    preg_match_all("#mvid:(\d+)\s+qty:(\d+)\s+name:([^:]+):(\w+)#", $content, $matches);

    $count = count($matches[1]); // we store the count of the elements so that we don't call the function in every iteration of for loop

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $values[$i] = $matches[1][$i]."|".$matches[2][$i]."|".$matches[3][$i]."|".$matches[4][$i];
    }

    echo "<pre>".print_r($values, true);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/789124

Comment: nice answer.+1 for worthy effort

Answer (score 0):

Here we are using `preg_split` to split on the basis of regular expression

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/789123)

```
<?php
$string='///mvid:417815 qty:2 name:Aether Hub loc:Deck
2 Aether Hub
///mvid:423770 qty:2 name:Aetherstream Leopard loc:Deck
2 Aetherstream Leopard
///mvid:401837 qty:4 name:Canopy Vista loc:Deck
4 Canopy Vista
///mvid:426709 qty:2 name:Cartouche of Solidarity loc:Deck
2 Cartouche of Solidarity';
$lines=explode("\n", $string);//optionally you can use file function to get the array of lines.
$result=array();
for($x=0;$x<count($lines);$x+=2)
{
    $split=preg_split("/[a-z]+:/",$lines[$x]);
    unset($split[0]);
    $result[]=implode("|",array_map("trim",array_values($split)));
}
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 417815|2|Aether Hub|Deck
    [1] => 423770|2|Aetherstream Leopard|Deck
    [2] => 401837|4|Canopy Vista|Deck
    [3] => 426709|2|Cartouche of Solidarity|Deck
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks that got me the info I needed to split the file up and load pieces into the array. From the array I could then make the form to select the appropriate cards to be displayed.

This is how I loaded the file:

```
$deck1 = [];
$maincount = 0;
$handle = @fopen("Deck1.dec", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
    preg_match_all("#mvid:(\d+)\s+qty:(\d+)\s+name:([^:]+):(\w+)#", $buffer, $matches);
    $count = count($matches[1]); 
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $deck1[$maincount][1] = $matches[1][$i];
        $deck1[$maincount][2] = $matches[2][$i];
        $deck1[$maincount][3] = rtrim($matches[3][$i], " loc");
        $deck1[$maincount][4] = $matches[4][$i];
    }
    $maincount++;
    }
    //echo "<pre>".print_r($deck1, true);
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

And this is how I created radio buttons. I needed to remove certain cards globally.

```
foreach ($deck1 as $index=>$option) {
    if ($option[3] != "Plains" && $option[3] != "Forest" && $option[3] != "Mountain" && $option[3] != "Swamp" && $option[3] != "Island"){
        if ($option[4] == "SB"){
            echo "<i><input type=\"radio\" name='mText7bgo' value=\"{$option[1]}\">{$option[3]}</i><br>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" name='mText7bgo' value=\"{$option[1]}\">{$option[3]}<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure there's some optimizing that could have been done, but this got the job done. Thanks.